# How can I submit child component's form in parent component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple code like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const ChildComponent = () => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => alert('Hello world !!!')}>
      <input name="hello" value='1' />
      <input name="world" value='2' />
    </form>
  );
}

function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <span>
      <ChildComponent />
      <button name='child-submit' type="submit">Show up !!!</button>
    </span>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ParentComponent />
  );
}
```

How can I submit form inside *ChildComponent* when I click submit button on *ParentComponent*?

Comment: Why are you using forms? You can use state management (redux/mobx/react-hooks) to monitor the change in values, then when clicking submit, do a server call with the latest values.

Comment: not needed to create a submit button in parent component,It should work in ChildComponent.

Comment: It's just sample.I have a  lot of similar form which is a bit different from others. I want to have a parent form to hold all child form, and every child forms have its own remote api to post data to. Ask me if my question does not clear. Thanks.

Comment: it's clear , whts the issue then ? each  child component will have their own submit right,since they have their own api to post data ?

Comment: Sure. They have their own remote api and data. That's why I want to have a dropdown to choose among their forms, and  want to one unify submit button. Any idea?